# Sorting A List In Custom Way

Tags: c#

Was trying to implement sorting of a `List<string>` in a custom way. Implemented the `IComparer<string>` interface, and it worked well. But after experimenting more with the `Sort` method of the list, I observed that this also works

```
list.Sort((s, s1) => {return s.ToLower().CompareTo(s1.ToLower()); });
```

But the MSDN documentation says nothing about the acceptance of a delegate as a parameter in the Sort method,neither the Intellisense shows an overload of this method which accepts a delegate.

So I would like to ask, that how did it worked?

Comment: Yes, it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You invoked [the overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) that takes a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) as an argument.

`Comparison<T>` is a delegate type, so the lambda function you provided fits the bill just right.